# Magento catalog price rule isn't calculating properly

Tags: magento, catalog, magento-rules

On my magento website version 1.7.0.2 and when we add a catalog price rule of 15% off any product the cart is actually calculating about 28% off the product cost. I can't find any documentation anywhere on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to test, do the products that you are using a catalog price rule against already have a special price instantiated on the product?   And you're saying 28% in the cart?    Are you sure you're referring to catalog price rule?   Shopping cart price rules are the ones that only affect the cart.   Provide a screen shot of your rule of the conditions and actions tab if its a shopping cart price rule or the catalog price rule and a screen shot of an example products price tab and I'd be glad to help